# Forcing Partition Query Using Laravel

Tags: laravel, partition

Hi I am currently writing a query where I would like to force the partition that the query uses. I know this code is working in MySQL but I don't know how I would write this using laravel.

This is the MySQL code I would use to force the partition

```
PARTITION (p46)
```

I have tried writing the following in Laravel but it doesn't seem to be working

```
->raw('PARTITION (p46)')
```

I'm not sure if `raw` is even a method you can use in laravel which is why it probably doesn't work.

I am using this partition enforcement instead of using the below code, it makes my queries much faster.

```
->where('venue_id', 46)
```

My table is partition using `HASH(venue_id)` and I have tried using the MySQL code and that is working perfectly.

Thank you in advance if you have a solution for this, I haven't been able to find anywhere which explains how to do this.

---

Here is my full laravel query to give you some context:

```
$bodyVisitors->selectRaw('SUM(visitors_new) AS new, SUM(visitors_total) AS total')
         ->raw('PARTITION (p' . $venue_filter . ')')
         ->where('day_epoch', '>=', $body_start)
         ->where('day_epoch', '<', $body_end)
         ->get();
```

The `->raw()` is being ignored is there anyway to make this work? I am fine if the answer is no, I will just stop using laravel to write those queries.

Comment: Which MySQL version?  The feature did not exist until 5.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

I also suffer the partition problem for whole day...

The way I solve is

select the max timestamp and max ID for T1 then left join it to the T2 on T1.timestamp and ID

Hope that my suggestion would give a some help...

I am still writing the eloquent script almost done :'(

Answer (score 0):

Try like this in your Eloquent Model:

```
$table = $this->getConnection()->getTablePrefix() . $this->getTable();
$table .= ' PARTITION ({your partition})';
$this->newQuery()->from($table)->where()->get();
```

that will be making a query like this:

`select * from table PARTITION (xxxxxx) where`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this scope

```
    {
        $query->from($partition);
    }
```

and `$partition` is a name of your partition. Try `$partition = 'p46'` in your case